# Android Application crashes at Uncaught exception in Firebase runloop (3.0.0)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an application in which i am using Firebase database. I need to retrieve some information from the database but the `addValueEventListener` does not fire at all and after couple of minutes my application crashes with following error
 `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: shareanddrive.net.net23.myapp, PID: 3317
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncaught exception in Firebase runloop (3.0.0). Please report to support@firebase.com
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzagf$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                   Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available`

However `adValuEventListener` works in previous activity but as i come second activity it stops working. I have checked the reference it is correct. My code for the retrieval in second activity is:

```
adsviewReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            textView.append("on add value datachange");

            }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            textView.setText("Failed ");
        }
    });
```

Neither of the function from `onDataChanged` or `onCancelled` fires.
Please help in this.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by using an incompatible version of Firebase Auth and the Firebase Realtime Database SDK. Please update your dependency of Firebase Auth and Firebase Database to the latest version. Check https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1086

Answer (score 0):

The exception you get is `OutOfMemoryError`. This means that you're trying to download more data from the database than your device has memory to handle.

The only way to solve this is to reduce the amount of data your app synchronizes at any one time. Things you can do:

1. Make sure that you [remove the listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#detach_listeners) from the previous activity on its `onStop()` or `onPause()`, so that the data from the previous activity can be removed from memory.
2. Attach your listener lower in the tree, so that less data is synchronized.